# Google accounts on Ice Cream Sandwich emulator

Tags: android, google-account, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to test an app that relies on Google accounts using the new ICS emulator, but I do no seem to have the option to add one (only email and business accounts.) Is that a bug or is it something that was left out on purpose. Can it be enabled via other settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure Emulator with Target name Google APIs instead of Android 4.0. Platform Version should be 4.0